Strange SBB behaviour
I have a code in which I have:
EAX=00002c36
and after:
SBB eax, 0
the eax turns:
EAX=00002c35
Is that possible?
Shouldn't eax be the same value?
If it's correct, it seems like I don't really understand the sbb instruction. Thanks in adv

Sbb is subtract with borrow check the  carry flags

Can you give me a link to a good reference about SBB instruction and how carry flag works because there's nothing on the web and I don't want to purchase assembly books, thanks

Or, if you would be so kind and explain it to me briefly

From Google Books:
"The SBB instruction subtracts the source operand from the destination operand and subtracts 1 if the carry flag is set..."
I think this is the answer.
